# Text over an image

Tags: bibtex

[image]

How can I reproduce this image? Any hint will be very well-received.

Comment: Combining the help from your last question with something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223186/easy-way-to-draw-ribbon may help/

Answer (score 3):

Literally copying Gonzalo's `\Ribbon[options]{text}` code at [Easy way to draw ribbon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223186/easy-way-to-draw-ribbon) and sticking it inside a `\stackinset` allows a direct solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}

\colorlet{color1}{gray!40}
\colorlet{color2}{gray}
\newlength\myrblen
\newlength\myrbht
\newlength\myrbarc
\setlength\myrblen{1cm}
\setlength\myrbht{3cm}
\setlength\myrbarc{8pt}

\makeatletter
\define@key{ribbonpar}{color1}{\colorlet{color1}{#1}}
\define@key{ribbonpar}{color2}{\colorlet{color2}{#1}}
\define@key{ribbonpar}{rblength}{\setlength\myrblen{#1}}
\define@key{ribbonpar}{rbheight}{\setlength\myrbht{#1}}
\define@key{ribbonpar}{rbarc}{\setlength\myrbarc{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\Ribbon[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\setkeys{ribbonpar}{#1}
\path
  (0,0) --
  ++(3\myrblen,0) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux1)
  ++(0,- \myrbarc) --
  ++(-\myrblen,0) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux2)
  ++(0,- \myrbarc) --
  ++(5\myrblen,0) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux3)
  ++(0, \myrbarc) --
  ++(-\myrblen,0) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux4)
  ++(0, \myrbarc) --
  ++(4\myrblen,0) --
  ++(-0.5\myrbht,-0.5\myrbht) --
  ++(0.5\myrbht,-0.5\myrbht) --
  ++(-11\myrblen,0) --
  ++(0.5\myrbht,0.5\myrbht) --
  ++(-0.5\myrbht,0.5\myrbht) --
    cycle;
\draw[fill=color2]
  (aux1) -- ++(0,-0.5\myrbht) coordinate (aux7) -- (aux2|-aux7) -- (aux2|-aux1) -- cycle;  
\draw[fill=color2]
  (aux4) -- ++(0,-0.5\myrbht) coordinate (aux8) -- (aux3|-aux8) -- (aux3|-aux4) -- cycle;  
\draw[thick,fill=color1]
  (0,0) --
  ++(3\myrblen,0) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux1)
  ++(0,- \myrbarc) --
  ++(-\myrblen,0) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux2)
  ++(0,- \myrbarc) --
  ++(5\myrblen,0) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux3)
  ++(0, \myrbarc) --
  ++(-\myrblen,0) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux4)
  ++(0, \myrbarc) --
  ++(4\myrblen,0) --
  ++(-0.5\myrbht,-0.5\myrbht) --
  ++(0.5\myrbht,-0.5\myrbht) --
  ++(-11\myrblen,0) --
  ++(0.5\myrbht,0.5\myrbht) --
  ++(-0.5\myrbht,0.5\myrbht) --
    cycle;
\path
  (aux2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- 
  ++(0,\dimexpr-\myrbht-1.5\myrbarc\relax) coordinate (aux5) -- 
  (aux3|-aux5)} -- 
  (aux3);
\fill[color1]
  ([yshift=-\myrbarc]aux2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- 
  ++(0,\dimexpr-\myrbht-0.5\myrbarc\relax) -- 
  (aux3|-aux5)} -- 
  ([yshift=-\myrbarc]aux3);
\draw
  (aux2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- 
  ++(0,\dimexpr-\myrbht-1.5\myrbarc\relax) coordinate (aux5) --  
  (aux3|-aux5)} -- 
  (aux3);
\node[
  anchor=north west,
  text width=\dimexpr5\myrblen-\myrbarc\relax,
  align=left,
  ] at ([xshift=\myrbarc,yshift=-\myrbarc]aux2)
  {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
\Ribbon[color1=orange!30,color2=orange!80,rblength=0.5cm,rbheight=2cm]{some text goes here}%
}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}}

\end{document}
```

[image]