# Draw ribbon with variable bending points

Tags: tikz-styles

I refer to the following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223186/easy-way-to-draw-ribbon) of Gonzalo Medina about creating a ribbon with text. I want to modify the existing code such that the points where the ribbon bends are quite large compared to the ends of the ribbon.

For example, the following code produces a long ribbon based on Gonzalo Medina's code. Yet the front part of the ribbon is short compared to the overall length of the ribbon. I want to control how long the front part should be, but have no idea how to change the code in order to reflect that.

```
\documentclass[a0, landscape]{sciposter} 
\usepackage{amsmath}                         
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}                        
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{suetterl}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{pagecolor} 
\usepackage{palatino} 

\colorlet{color1}{gray!40}
\colorlet{color2}{gray}
\newlength\myrblen
\newlength\myrbht
\newlength\myrbarc
\setlength\myrblen{1cm}
\setlength\myrbht{3cm}
\setlength\myrbarc{8pt}
\makeatletter
\define@key{ribbonpar}{color1}{\colorlet{color1}{#1}}
\define@key{ribbonpar}{color2}{\colorlet{color2}{#1}}
\define@key{ribbonpar}{rblength}{\setlength\myrblen{#1}}
\define@key{ribbonpar}{rbheight}{\setlength\myrbht{#1}}
\define@key{ribbonpar}{rbarc}{\setlength\myrbarc{#1}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\Ribbon[2][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \setkeys{ribbonpar}{#1}
    \path
    (0,0) --
    ++(3\myrblen,0) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux1)
    ++(0,- \myrbarc) --
    ++(-\myrblen,0) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux2)
    ++(0,- \myrbarc) --
    ++(5\myrblen,0) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux3)
    ++(0, \myrbarc) --
    ++(-\myrblen,0) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux4)
    ++(0, \myrbarc) --
    ++(4\myrblen,0) --
    ++(-0.5\myrbht,-0.5\myrbht) --
    ++(0.5\myrbht,-0.5\myrbht) --
    ++(-11\myrblen,0) --
    ++(0.5\myrbht,0.5\myrbht) --
    ++(-0.5\myrbht,0.5\myrbht) --
    cycle;
    \draw[fill=color2]
    (aux1) -- ++(0,-0.5\myrbht) coordinate (aux7) -- (aux2|-aux7) -- (aux2|-aux1) -- cycle;  
    \draw[fill=color2]
    (aux4) -- ++(0,-0.5\myrbht) coordinate (aux8) -- (aux3|-aux8) -- (aux3|-aux4) -- cycle;  
    \draw[thick,fill=color1]
    (0,0) --
    ++(3\myrblen,0) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux1)
    ++(0,- \myrbarc) --
    ++(-\myrblen,0) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux2)
    ++(0,- \myrbarc) --
    ++(5\myrblen,0) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux3)
    ++(0, \myrbarc) --
    ++(-\myrblen,0) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=3] coordinate[midway] (aux4)
    ++(0, \myrbarc) --
    ++(4\myrblen,0) --
    ++(-0.5\myrbht,-0.5\myrbht) --
    ++(0.5\myrbht,-0.5\myrbht) --
    ++(-11\myrblen,0) --
    ++(0.5\myrbht,0.5\myrbht) --
    ++(-0.5\myrbht,0.5\myrbht) --
    cycle;
    \path
    (aux2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- 
        ++(0,\dimexpr-\myrbht-1.5\myrbarc\relax) coordinate (aux5) -- 
        (aux3|-aux5)} -- 
    (aux3);
    \fill[color1]
    ([yshift=-\myrbarc]aux2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- 
        ++(0,\dimexpr-\myrbht-0.5\myrbarc\relax) -- 
        (aux3|-aux5)} -- 
    ([yshift=-\myrbarc]aux3);
    \draw
    (aux2) {[rounded corners=6pt] -- 
        ++(0,\dimexpr-\myrbht-1.5\myrbarc\relax) coordinate (aux5) --  
        (aux3|-aux5)} -- 
    (aux3);
    \node[
    anchor=north west,
    text width=\dimexpr5\myrblen-\myrbarc\relax,
    align=left,
    ] at ([xshift=\myrbarc,yshift=-\myrbarc]aux2)
    {#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{center} \Ribbon[color1 = white, rblength=9cm,rbheight=3cm, rbarc=1cm]{\begin{center}\Huge{\calligra This title is way tooooooo long to display it here without a line break} \end{center}}\bigskip \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Welcome! This is an attempt to solve the problem you are facing, and to provide you a version that can be customized more easily. It provides a pic, the appearance of which is controlled by pgf keys, with some explanations in the annotations. If you wish to have more parameters to play with and/or other default/initial values, please let me know.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{pics/ribbon/.style={code={
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ribbon/##1}}
 \node[alias=aux,/tikz/ribbon/node]{#1};
 \fill[\pv{shadow color}]
   (aux.north west) arc(-90:-270:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (\pv{inset},0) arc(-90:00:\pv{arc radius})
   -- ([xshift=\pv{inset}+\pv{arc radius}]aux.north west)
   (aux.north east) arc(-90:90:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (-\pv{inset},0) arc(-90:-180:\pv{arc radius})
   -- ([xshift=-\pv{inset}-\pv{arc radius}]aux.north east);
 \draw let \p1=($(aux.north)-(aux.south)$) in 
  % little stretch south west
   (aux.south west) arc(-90:-180:\pv{arc radius}) -- ++ (0,\y1)
  % big stretch north west 
   (aux.north west) arc(-90:-270:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (\pv{inset},0) arc(-90:90:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (-\pv{outset},0) -- ++(\y1/2,-\y1/2)
   -- ++(-\y1/2,-\y1/2) -- 
   ([yshift=4*\pv{arc radius},xshift=-\pv{arc radius}]aux.south west)
  % little stretch south east
   (aux.south east) arc(-90:0:\pv{arc radius}) -- ++ (0,\y1)
  % big stretch north east 
   (aux.north east) arc(-90:90:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (-\pv{inset},0) arc(-90:-270:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (\pv{outset},0) -- ++(-\y1/2,-\y1/2)
   -- ++(\y1/2,-\y1/2) -- 
   ([yshift=4*\pv{arc radius},xshift=\pv{arc radius}]aux.south east)
  % top
   (aux.north west) -- (aux.north east)
  % bottom
   (aux.south west) -- (aux.south east);
}},
ribbon/.cd,node/.style={align=center,inner xsep=5pt},%<- controls the node options
arc radius/.initial=2pt,%<- self-explaining (?)
inset/.initial=1cm,%<- horizontal distance of the lower horizontal stretches
outset/.initial=2cm,%<- horizontal distance of the upper horizontal stretches
shadow color/.initial=gray!80}%<- self-explaining (?)
\newcommand{\TikZRibbon}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{ribbon/.cd,#1}
\pic{ribbon={#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\TikZRibbon[node/.append style={font=\Huge\calligra,inner xsep=2em},inset=3cm,outset=5cm]{%
This title is long but there is no poblem displaying it here without a line break~}

\TikZRibbon[node/.append style={font=\Huge\calligra,inner xsep=2em},
    inset=3cm,outset=6cm,arc radius=7pt]{%
This title is very long and\\ if we add line breaks\\
there is not problem, the ribbon adjusts~}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Just for fun: a slightly fancier version. Notice that both pics are called `ribbon` but the version below differs from the one above.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{pics/ribbon/.style={code={
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ribbon/##1}}
 \node[alias=aux,/tikz/ribbon/node]{#1};
 \path[ribbon/shadow]
   (aux.north west) arc(-90:-270:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (\pv{inset},0) arc(-90:00:\pv{arc radius})
   -- ([xshift=\pv{inset}+\pv{arc radius}]aux.north west);
 \path[ribbon/shadow]  (aux.north east) arc(-90:90:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (-\pv{inset},0) arc(-90:-180:\pv{arc radius})
   -- ([xshift=-\pv{inset}-\pv{arc radius}]aux.north east);
 \path[ribbon/outer] let \p1=($(aux.north)-(aux.south)$) in 
  % little stretch south west
   ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]aux.south west) arc(-90:-180:\pv{arc radius}) -- ++ (0,\y1)
    arc(180:270:\pv{arc radius})
  % little stretch south east
   ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]aux.south east) arc(-90:0:\pv{arc radius}) -- ++ (0,\y1)
    arc(0:-90:\pv{arc radius});
 \path[ribbon/back] let \p1=($(aux.north)-(aux.south)$) in 
  % big stretch north west 
   ([xshift=-\pv{arc radius},yshift=\pv{arc radius}]aux.north west) arc(180:90:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (\pv{inset},0) arc(-90:90:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (-\pv{outset},0) -- ++(\y1/2,-\y1/2)
   -- ++(-\y1/2,-\y1/2) -- 
   ([yshift=4*\pv{arc radius},xshift=-\pv{arc radius}]aux.south west)
   -- cycle
  % big stretch north east 
   ([xshift=\pv{arc radius},yshift=\pv{arc radius}]aux.north east) 
   arc(0:90:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (-\pv{inset},0) arc(-90:-270:\pv{arc radius}) 
   -- ++ (\pv{outset},0) -- ++(-\y1/2,-\y1/2)
   -- ++(\y1/2,-\y1/2) -- 
   ([yshift=4*\pv{arc radius},xshift=\pv{arc radius}]aux.south east)
   -- cycle
  % top
   (aux.north west) -- (aux.north east)
  % bottom
   (aux.south west) -- (aux.south east);
}},
ribbon/.cd,node/.style={align=center,inner xsep=5pt},%<- controls the node options
arc radius/.initial=3pt,%<- self-explaining (?)
inset/.initial=1cm,%<- horizontal distance of the lower horizontal stretches
outset/.initial=2cm,%<- horizontal distance of the upper horizontal stretches
back/.style={draw},%<-ribbon pieces in the background
outer/.style={draw},%<- left and right band of the ribbon
shadow/.style={fill=gray!80}}%<- self-explaining (?)
\newcommand{\TikZRibbon}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{ribbon/.cd,#1}
\pic{ribbon={#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\TikZRibbon[node/.append style={font=\bfseries\sffamily\Huge,inner xsep=2em,
inner ysep=1em,fill=white},
outer/.append style={fill=white},
back/.append style={fill=white},inset=3cm,outset=5cm]{%
Happy Thanksgiving!}

\TikZRibbon[node/.append style={font=\bfseries\sffamily\Huge,inner xsep=2em,
inner ysep=1em,text=white,left color=blue!40!black,right color=blue!40!black,
middle color=blue,shading angle=20},
shadow/.style={left color=gray,right color=black,shading
angle=0},
outer/.append style={fill=blue!40!black,draw=blue!40!black,semithick},
back/.append style={left color=blue!70!black,right color=blue!60!black,middle color=blue!40!black,
shading angle=45},inset=3cm,outset=5cm]{%
Happy Thanksgiving!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. The first version is exactly what I intended. A special thanks for your comments explaining the code :-)

Comment: One followup question though: When using your ribbon together with the background package, i.e. setting an image as background, it is not possible to fill the ribbon. Instead the ribbon is transparent and shows the background image. How to fix that?

Comment: @Taufi The lower code has a ribbon that is filled. I added a version that is filled white, i.e. not transparent. Of course, you can make the font `\calligra` and so on as in the upper examples.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this does not work with the background image as I described it. It keeps being transparent. Is there some special option to force the ribbon to overlay on the background image?

Comment: @Taufi Would you mind asking a separate question on this where you show the code that you use explicitly? Asking questions is free, and I feel that I just misinterpret your comment a bit because I explicitly added the white ribbon of the lower code on top of a graphics, and it was not transparent. That is, there is something in your code that I did not add, which is why the full code is important, and if you ask a separate question, more users will look at it.

Comment: Of course, thanks again for what you provided so far. It was very helpful!