# Design assignment pdf front page

Tags: book-design

How can I design PDF page like this : 
[image]

Comment: Hi! In addition to the screenshot, do you have a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried so far?

Comment: There is a beautiful solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223229/220875