# Colour two sides of a ribbon?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I didn't expected the following intersection in my graph (here, for sake of minimalism, only locally exposed). Now, I need to know, how to colour the two sides of the ribbon I (locally) drew as follows:

[image]

How to constrain the filling to the curves in the wished area?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[double,blue, opacity=.39,
double distance=1.0 pt,thick,smooth] plot[smooth ] coordinates{
    (12.68,-.96)  (12.68-.085,-.96-.063) (12.68+.25, -.96+0.001)  (12.68+.282, -.96+.1)  
    (12.68,-.96) } ;

\draw[ opacity=.4]
(12.68,-.96) ..controls +( .4,.083) and +( .1,-.0811 ) ..  (12.88,-.75)  ;

\draw[ opacity=.4]
(12.61,-1.01) ..controls +( .46,.05) and +( .135,-.0811 ) ..  (12.839,-.81)  ;

 % second, non-smooth attempt
\begin{scope}[xshift=.5cm] 
 \fill[double, red!60!black, opacity=.39,
  double distance=1.0 pt]
    (12.68,-.96) --  +(-.085, -.063) -- +(.255, 0.001)  -- +(.289, .1) --  (12.68,-.96)  ; 


\draw[ opacity=.4]
(12.68,-.96) ..controls +( .4,.083) and +( .1,-.0811 ) ..  (12.88,-.75)  ;

\draw[ opacity=.4]
(12.61,-1.01) ..controls +( .46,.05) and +( .135,-.0811 ) ..  (12.839,-.81)  ;   
 \end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps this question is relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223186/easy-way-to-draw-ribbon

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I saw it, but this is rather about twisting. If I find the solution there, I'll post it here.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156327/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but will hopefully get you going in the right direction. If I understand it correctly, this question is a difficult one, since you are essentially trying to find the "maximum" point of a bent curve so that you can fill up the space to that point. The naive solution is to use `\fill` with the same path coordinates you have, reversing one of the paths:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[ opacity=.4]
(12.68,-.96) ..controls +( .4,.083) and +( .1,-.0811 ) ..  (12.88,-.75)  ;

\draw[ opacity=.4]
(12.61,-1.01) ..controls +( .46,.05) and +( .135,-.0811 ) ..  (12.839,-.81)  ;

\fill[ opacity=.4,color=blue]
(12.61,-1.01) ..controls +( .46,.05) and +( .135,-.0811 ) ..  (12.839,-.81)  
--
(12.88,-.75) .. controls +( .1,-.0811 ) and +( .4,.083) .. (12.68,-.96);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

You see that part of the "ribbon" is filled, but not around the area where the two curves "turn back" and change direction:

[image]

My initial thought is to use [`tikz-3dplot`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot?lang=en) because the ribbon you're trying to replicate somehow exists in 3 dimensions, and so with that package you can find a suitable projection of it - but actually drawing it in 3 dimensions also seems very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution given by jlv,

[image]

```
 \begin{scope}
        \clip (12.61,-1.01) rectangle (12.97,-.888)  ;
    \fill[ opacity=.4,color=blue]
    (12.61,-1.01) ..controls +( .46,.05) and +( .135,-.0811 ) ..  (12.839,-.81)  
    --
    (12.88,-.75) .. controls +( .1,-.0811 ) and +( .4,.083) .. (12.68,-.96);
    \end{scope} 


\begin{scope}
    \clip  (12.57,-.877) rectangle (13,-.477)  ;
\fill[ opacity=.4,color=red]
(12.61,-1.01) ..controls +( .46,.05) and +( .135,-.0811 ) ..  (12.839,-.81)  
--
(12.88,-.75) .. controls +( .1,-.0811 ) and +( .4,.083) .. (12.68,-.96);
\end{scope}
```